# Attempting to use a marker interface fails with IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container, auto-registration

I am attempting to mimic some stuff from Orchard CMS in my own app using unity..

Okay so what I am trying to do is this...

Lets say I have a marker interface called IDependency..

```
public interface IDependency{ }
```

I then have several interfaces hanging off of this...

```
public interface ICustomerService : IDependency { }

public interface ICustomerRepository : IDependency { }
```

and then have some classes too...

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService {
     public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepo){ }
}

public class SomOtherCustomerService : ICustomerService {
     public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepo){ }
}

public class NicksController : Controller {
     public NicksController(IEnumerable<ICustomerService> customerServices) { }
}

 public class NicksSecondController : Controller {
     public NicksSecondController(IEnumerable<ICustomerService> customerServices) { }
}
```

What I have so far..

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container
    .ConfigureAutoRegistration()
    .ExcludeSystemAssemblies()
    //.Include(If.Implements<IDependency>, Then.Register()
    //.As<IDependency>().UsingLifetime<PerResolveLifetimeManager>())
    .Include(t =>
        typeof(IDependency).IsAssignableFrom(t), (type, builder) =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType(type);

                foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(itf => typeof(IDependency).IsAssignableFrom(itf))) {
                    builder = builder.RegisterType(interfaceType, type);
                }
            })
    .ApplyAutoRegistration();
```

Im falling down on the injecting of an IEnumerable in to my NicksSecondController... Any Ideas??

Cheers, Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box Unity only knows how to resolve arrays. Have a look at the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com). It contains a custom extension that teaches the container to handle `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` as well. The code can be found in *TecX.Unity* (folder *Collections*).